# Tracking Play and Apple store app download sources in Google Analytics

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-play, app-store

Is it possible to track app downloads sources from both (google and apple) marketplaces in Google Analytics or do I have to use another tool for that purpose?

I mean I'd like to know what was the referring source that lead that user to the play/apple store page where he tapped [download]

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible in GA. They CAN be tracked within the Google Play Console or App Store Connect. Similar to campaign tracking for web, you'll need to create specific links OR use the default tracking.

Reference:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns

https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/itcfa7936330?sub=apdff205b72c0994